# Why are np.empty((1,), dtype=np.bool_) or global arrays slow as default arguments in numba?

Tags: python, numpy, performance, numba

I was writing a function in numba which requires an optional argument to be an array of any dtype, and was experimenting with putting a default array directly in the function definition, and noticed that using `np.empty` or a global array was ~80x slower than using `array` or `zeros`. Why is using these functions in a function definition so slow, when neither of these functions are that slow in normal python or in an njit function:

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.njit
def func_zeros(b=np.zeros((1,), dtype=np.bool_)):
    return b

@nb.njit
def func_array(b=np.array(0, dtype=np.bool_)):
    return b

@nb.njit
def func_empty(b=np.empty((1,), dtype=np.bool_)):
    return b

_global_array = np.zeros((1,), dtype=np.bool_)

@nb.njit
def func_global(b=_global_array):
    return b

@nb.njit
def func_None(b=None):
    if b is None:
        b = np.empty((1,), dtype=np.bool_)
    return b

func_zeros(), func_array(), func_empty(), func_global(), func_None()
func_zeros(np.zeros((1,), dtype=np.bool_))
func_array(np.array(0, dtype=np.bool_))
func_empty(np.empty((1,), dtype=np.bool_))
func_global(np.zeros((1,), dtype=np.bool_))
func_None(np.empty((1,), dtype=np.bool_))

%timeit -n 10000 func_zeros()
%timeit -n 10000 func_array()
%timeit -n 10000 func_empty()
%timeit -n 10000 func_global()
%timeit -n 10000 func_None()
%timeit -n 10000 func_zeros(np.zeros((1,), dtype=np.bool_))
%timeit -n 10000 func_array(np.array(0, dtype=np.bool_))
%timeit -n 10000 func_empty(np.empty((1,), dtype=np.bool_))
%timeit -n 10000 func_global(np.zeros((1,), dtype=np.bool_))
%timeit -n 10000 func_None(np.empty((1,), dtype=np.bool_))
```

Output:

```
296 ns ± 2.73 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
291 ns ± 5.45 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
24.4 µs ± 166 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each) #!!!
24.4 µs ± 262 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each) #!!!
357 ns ± 5.69 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
463 ns ± 3.96 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
532 ns ± 4.17 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
468 ns ± 5.55 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
472 ns ± 6.65 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
475 ns ± 4.68 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

Secondary question, I'm running this in a Jupyter notebook in vscode, the times above are for the first time I run this cell after restarting the kernel, if I run the cell a second time, I get the following times:

```
25 µs ± 728 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
23.1 µs ± 186 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
24.5 µs ± 477 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
23.8 µs ± 145 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
356 ns ± 4.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
466 ns ± 4.61 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
505 ns ± 3.59 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
456 ns ± 2.78 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
464 ns ± 2.61 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
458 ns ± 4.36 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

if these are the correct times, why is using arrays as default arguments so slow in numba, and if not, why is this happening?

Comment: It's an interesting observation, and I can replicate it, inc running twice. I have to run the cell declaring the functions again to trigger the change. Calling the functions twice (with or without timeit) doesn't seem to impact it. Part of it is calling `func_array` with a 0D array, if you make that a similar 1D array that one also slows down. I can't explain why `func_zeros` remains so much faster (initially), the llvm looks identical to me (no expert).

Comment: Note btw that it's usually not a good idea to use a default argument that's mutable. It has it's usecase, but often people do it unintentionally. And with Numba you can for example even crash the interpreter (kernel) if you modify the result from one of your functions, and call it again (again without providing the argument). The default value is created when declaring the function (once!), not at every call again.

Comment: Noted about the mutable default arguments. In my actual function, this argument is passed to an external c function, which passes it to a user defined numba cfunc in which it shouldn't be modified so I was looking for a way to make something with a ctypes attribute without having to create an unnecessary array every time the function is called, which I guess I could do with `overload`.